# Is there any reliable solution to make background music autoplay in a HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, cross-browser, autoplay

I am trying to make a music automatically playing when a HTML page is loaded. I tried different things but without success.

I searched through stackoverflow to find a good solution, but didn't manage to find a strong workaround that works with all browsers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Best Regards,
Cedric

Comment: use one audio and play on page load, thats it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the `autoplay` attribute works on some cases, you should know that in many cases it doesn't. I suggest you read [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide) to understand why and also get some ideas how to adapt to the limitations.

Comment: Thank you for the MDN article, it helped me lot. I used their fallback solution, and it works well when autoplay doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The `<audio>` element with the `autoplay` attribute should be sufficient. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio

It is extremely well supported.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that "autoplay" is not supported anymore in Mozilla Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Ah yes, true! I guess it is a silent moral judgement on the choice to use autoplay haha!

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will work for you ! Works perfectly fine for me!

`<audio controls autoplay>
  <source src="audiofile.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<audio controls autoplay>
  <source src="music.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```